# Cant get my code to generate enough fields for bingo

Tags: python

I need my program to generate as many playing fields as the entered number of players playing the game. Currently it only generates 1 field. Cant wrap my head around this one.

````
s = int(input("Sisesta mängijate arv: "))
b = int(input("Sisesta väjaku suurus: "))
b = b + 1
bb = b
c = int(input("Sisesta korrutustabeli suurus: "))
for s in range (1 , s+1):
    numberolemas = ['0']
    t.write(str(s) + ". väljak \n\n")
    print(str(s) + ". väljak \n")
    for bb in range (1 , bb):
        for b in range (1 , b):
            import random
            number = random.randint(1, c) * random.randint(1, c)
            olemas = True
            while olemas:
                number = random.randint(1, c) * random.randint(1, c)
                if number not in numberolemas:
                    olemas = False
            t.write(str(number))
            print(str(number), end = ' ')
            if number <= 9:
                t.write("   ")
                print("   ", end = '')
            elif number >= 100:
                t.write(" ")
                print(" ", end = '') 
            else: t.write("  ") and print("  ", end = '')
            numberolemas.append(number)
        b = b + 1
        t.write("\n\n")
        print(" ")
    bb = bb + 1
    print(" ")



t.close() ```
````

Comment: Don't use the same variable like this: `for bb in range (1 , bb)`

Comment: @Barmar not sure i quite understand how to fix that. Im fairly new to coding sorry.

Comment: `for othervariable in range(1, bb):`